# Horizontal Bar chart not moving to X

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-charts

Today i finally got my autolayout constrainst animation to work, and after that i noticed, that the Horizontal bar chart isnt behaving like it used to be.

I have a Horizontal Bar chart populated with data in Descending order (the most should be on top) but the problem is, whenever i try to move the view back to the first entry (the biggest value) using moveViewToX the chart just doesn't do anything it always shows the last added entry, so its scrolled to the end.

[image: chart scrolled to last entry]

I'd like to have it start from the top, i mean from the first entry.

[image: the desired chart]

I have tried the moveViewToX function, but it still has no effect.
Here's the code for setting the data:

```
let sortedData = chartData.sorted(by: { $0.money < $1.money })

    for i in 0..<sortedData.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(sortedData[i].money))
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        labels2.append(sortedData[i].Name)
    }
```

Here is the setup for the chart:

```
let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "kategoriak")
    chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor.red]

    let kerekitöFormatter = KerekitöNumberFormatter(showZeros: false, showMoney: true)
    chartDataSet.valueFormatter = kerekitöFormatter
    chartDataSet.valueFont = chartDataSet.valueFont.withSize(10)
    chartDataSet.valueTextColor = .white

    let horChartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

    horizontalChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = BarChartXaxisFormatter(labels: labels2, truncMode: true)

    horizontalChartView.data = horChartData
    horizontalChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0

    horizontalChartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = YAxisValueFormatter()

    horizontalChartView.legend.enabled = false
    horizontalChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

    horizontalChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5)
    horizontalChartView.moveViewToX(Double(sortedData.count))
    horizontalChartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false
    horizontalChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    //horizontalChartView.setExtraOffsets (left: 0.0, top: 0.0, right:0.0, bottom: 0.0)
    horizontalChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
    horizontalChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false


    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        horizontalChartView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        horizontalChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = .label
        horizontalChartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = .label
        horizontalChartView.gridBackgroundColor = .label

    }

    let rightAxis = horizontalChartView.rightAxis
    rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    rightAxis.enabled = false
```

I hope someone can help.
Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: What do you mean by: "whenever i try to scroll back to the first entry (the biggest value) the chart just doesn't do anything it always shows the last added entry, so its scrolled to the end." Do you mean that the chart displays correctly, but once you scroll the red bars don't align correctly?

Comment: @rs7 when the chart is loaded it looks like the first image, and when i manually scroll (using my finger) back i see that everything is loaded. By scrolling i mean whenever i try to use the moveViewToX function to show the first entry, it does not work. I want my chart to look like the second image.

Comment: What does moveViewToX do? Can you share more of that code. Are you saying, when you horizontally scroll to the right and scroll back to the left, your screen looks like 1 instead of 2?

Comment: @rs7 moveViewToX is a class function of the chart. It should move the view to the defined position, in my case to entry number one. This is a Horizontal bar chart you can only scroll from top to bottom. When I’m opening the app and the chart is loaded I see image 1 (so it is showing the last added entries) but I want to show the first added entries. Like in image 2.

Comment: Can you share the function moveViewToX since it is the problematic function here.

Comment: @rs7 I will say it one more time. moveViewToX is not a function written by me, it’s a function of the charts framework. Everything was working fine, until I used auto layout.

Comment: You've never mentioned you were using a framework in the first place ;) Glad you figured out what your issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research and trying i figured it out. For some strange reason if you use moveViewToX it does not respond, but when you use moveViewTo(float xValue, float yValue, AxisDependency axis) it works.

So, to be short, i added this line of code at the end of setting up the chart.

```
horizontalChartView.moveViewTo(xValue: Double(sortedData.count), yValue: sortedData.first!.money, axis: .left)
```

Hope this helps you in the future!